# Create custom builder that works like Spring DataSourceBuilder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to mimic the behaviour of Springs Boot `DataSourceBuilder` when you can define multiple datasources with a code like this.

```java
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("dataflow")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dataflow")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("task")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "task")
    public DataSource taskDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
```

I've developed some solution based on this question [Binding @ConfigurationProperties to builder used to create bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51983637/binding-configurationproperties-to-builder-used-to-create-bean) and it works as described below.

I'm trying to create multiple `Foo` objects based on `ConfigurationProperties` prefix. `Foo` class looks like this.

**Foo.java**

```java
public class Foo {
    private String name, surname;

    public Foo(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I've also created simple `FooBuilder`

**FooBuilder.java**

```java
public class FooBuilder {
    private String name, surname;

    public static FooBuilder create(){
        return new FooBuilder();
    }

    public FooBuilder name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public FooBuilder surname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
        return this;
    }

    public Foo build(){
        return new Foo(name,surname);
    }
}
```

then I created `FooProperites` component which has `initializeBuilder` method.

**FooProperties.java**

```java
@Component
public class FooProperties {
    private String name, surname;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public FooBuilder initializeBuilder(){
        return FooBuilder.create().name(getName()).surname(getSurname());
    }
}
```

Then I create some `InitConfiguration` class for later use with `InitTest` `CommandLineRunner`

**InitConfiguration.java**

```java
@Configuration
public class InitConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("t1.foo")
    public FooProperties firstFooProperties() {
        return new FooProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public Foo firstFoo(FooProperties firstFooProperties) {
        return firstFooProperties.initializeBuilder().build();
    }


    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("t2.foo")
    public FooProperties secondFooProperties() {
        return new FooProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public Foo secondFoo(FooProperties secondFooProperties) {
        return secondFooProperties.initializeBuilder().build();
    }
}
```

**InitTest.java**

```java
@Component
public class InitTest implements CommandLineRunner {
    private Foo foo1,foo2;

    public InitTest(Foo firstFoo, Foo secondFoo) {
        this.foo1 = firstFoo;
        this.foo2 = secondFoo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(foo1);
        System.out.println(foo2);
    }

}
```

Based on following `application.properties` file:

```
t1.foo.name=a
t1.foo.surname=b

t2.foo.name=x
t2.foo.surname=z
```

everything works fine, and the following output is produced:

```
Foo{name='a', surname='b'}
Foo{name='x', surname='z'}
```

The question is how to make the same outcome without explicitly defining properties beans, so that the code in initConfiguration could look something like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class InitConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("t2.foo")
    public Foo firstFoo() {
        return FooBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("t2.foo")
    public Foo secondFoo() {
        return FooBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
Foo{name='null', surname='null'}
Foo{name='null', surname='null'}
```

It works the same when written that way:

```java
@Configuration
public class InitConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("t1.foo")
    public Foo firstFoo(FooProperties properties) {
        return properties.initializeBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("t2.foo")
    public Foo secondFoo(FooProperties properties) {
        return properties.initializeBuilder().build();
    }
}
```

I quess it has something to do with auto configuration feature of `Spring Boot`but I can't figure it out from Spring implementations of `DataSourceBuilder`, `DataSourceProperties`, `DataSourceConfiguration`, `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`. 
The question is... how to achieve that?

Please find my GitLab repo for this problem [HERE](https://gitlab.com/najczuk-edu/spring-properties-driven-builder).

Comment: Are you asking, how to use these `@Bean`s that you have created here? I can see they're being used in `InitConfiguration` implementation. What about this `DataSource` configuration. What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @SachithDickwella I think the question is well described. I want to be able to create Foo bean using following notation:
`@Bean @ConfigurationProperties("t2.foo") public Foo firstFoo() { return FooBuilder.create().build(); }`. I've mentioned `DataSourceBuilder` just to show that it is possible, but the guestion is how to achieve that.